# How to change hugepages in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, grub

I try to reserving Hugepages for DPDK Use. I change the configuration in /etc/default/grub like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="crashkernel=1G-:256M quiet default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=50"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="eagerfpu=on cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=0 nopti"
```

and I run

```
#update-grub
#reboot
```

but it didn't work. Although I find this in /boot/grub/grib.cfg

```
# grep 'hugepages' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=4efa0660-cd6c-4d8e-831b-bf217bf15915 ro eagerfpu=on cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=0 nopti crashkernel=1G-:256M quiet default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=50
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=4efa0660-cd6c-4d8e-831b-bf217bf15915 ro eagerfpu=on cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 processor.max_cstate=0 nopti crashkernel=1G-:256M quiet default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=50
```

the /proc/meminfo stays the same:

```
# grep '^Huge' /proc/meminfo
HugePages_Total:      32
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
```

by the way, this is my OS:

```
# uname -a
Linux n15-063-139 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u5 (2017-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am really a new hand to dpdk, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the cause. It is kexec. When I run *reboot*, this server will reboot though kexec, and in /etc/default/kexec:

```
    # Load the default kernel from grub config (true/false)
    USE_GRUB_CONFIG=false
```

so the hugepage config is not in operation. I change the 'false' to 'true', and run *reboot*. The problem is solved.
Or I should just run *reboot -f*, not to contact the init system.